# Achieved Fix width and height of any HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 questions and I am entirely new to use of CSS and I have mainly coded all logical based coding not in UI so just trying to fix up my logical coding in UI.

**Question 1.**  Well I was thinking that is there any way to fix the width and height of any HTML element.

For Example: If I want to have fixed width and height of button

**HTML**

```
<button class="test12"></button>
```

**CSS**

```
.test12{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
```

this height and width styling can be changed from an external source, but I want to achieve such a thing that height and width of any div, button, input, etc cannot be changed it will be fixed.

**Questions 2:** is there any way to achieve this fixed height and width of HTML element with same code like for table to have fixed layout we use table-layout: fixed, but for the button, input, etc we have to write another syntax. So is there any familiar syntax for this fixed width and height of the HTML element.

**The reason I have tagged jquery, javascript because if the answer to my questions can be achieved using javascript and jquery,  I am okay with it**

**Question 1 is answered by Nilesh Naik, Question 2 is still on hold**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `!important` property to your css rules. This will not change the width of the button(in your case) even if some JS is trying to change it externally. Try clicking on the button in the snippet. And then remove the `!important` property and try clicking on the button again.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test12");
    x[0].style.width = "300px";
}
```

```css
.test12 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px!important;
}
```

```html
<button class="test12" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

Comment: I have read somewhere that using !important is not a good practice of coding ,so any alternative ?

Comment: can you answer my Question 2

Comment: With respect to question 1 there are cases when using `!imoprtant` is the right choice. Here is the link for you to read on such cases https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ 

With respect to question 2 i don't think there is any such property.